# Repack and export a java project as an executable

Tags: java, eclipse

I made my first application with Java in Eclipse now I need to repackage or create an executable file file from that project. I used a lot of external jar libraries that I would like to export whit the project. Any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [apache maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to make a fat jar in conjunction with the [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/links.html) maven plugin to make an self-contained exe (i.e. a wrapper for the jar).

Answer (score 0):

you can make a executable jar file of that project. And then make a .bat file. From that .bat file you can invoke that executable jar.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will pack you yourprojectname.jar file, which is executable file. So, in order to run it you may just run in command line (a.k.a `cmd`) `java -jar path/to/your/project.jar`. And of course it is more easier to run it with script. There are .bat files which are something like .bash scripts in linux/unix

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your Eclipse project in ProjectExplorer
2. Export...
3. Java\Runnable jar file
4. On dialog Runnable JAR file export

4.1. Choose the main() method you need to start from the popup "Launch configuration"

4.2. Specify the output jar like: d:\dest.jar

4.3. "Finish'